# Spring annotations @Repository and @Service

Tags: spring

What are the advantages of using [@Repository](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html) and [@Service](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html)?

Don't tell me about component scanning etc., I am looking forward to something extra benefits or features that are there if at all.

what happens if I don't use it? what is that I would be missing?

Answer (score 73):

There are a few reasons:

1. It's easier to target pointcuts with more specific annotations. Do *not* underestimate the usefulness of this!
2. The `@Repository` annotation carries with it some additional functionality: it causes exceptions to be [wrapped up as `DataAccessException`s](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.M2/api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html).
3. The `@Service` annotation [may gain additional semantics in the future](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?45397-What-is-the-Service-annotation&p=147796#post147796) but it's not happened yet…

Comment: is it DataAccessException or PersistenceException?

Comment: @veer7 `DataAccessException`, like the docs say. Why do you ask?

Answer (score 65):

The `@Repository` annotation (introduced in Spring 2.0) and `@Service` annotation (introduced in Spring 2.5) are specialization of the `@Component` annotation.

The main advantage of using `@Repository` or `@Service` over `@Component` is that it's easy to write an AOP pointcut that targets, for instance, all classes annotated with `@Repository`.

Also, the specialized annotations help to clearly demarcate application layers (in a standard 3 tiers application).

Comment: Official doc: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-stereotype-annotations

Answer (score 5):

I believe that there are two things Spring had in mind when they added these Component annotations.

1. They can be used to specify point cuts across all objects annotated with that sub-component.  (All @Repository or all @Service pointcuts)
2. I think Spring also mentioned that they would be adding some future functionality to them.  (I have no citation for this, I just think I read this somewhere)

Answer (score 3):

If you [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) it would be useful to carefully design (an test of course) @Services because they will benefit of full injection of all the @Autowired components you have defined.

You could implement your functionalities directly into a @Controller for example, but in this case testing will be harder and you need to define all the mock elements (quite easier in springframework 3.1 but still "bad design").